# reusing a layout

Tags: android, layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcY6K.png)Good day , I am new to android development and I am trying to put image next to edittext and then have three of them listed underneath each other. It needs to be in one layout because i need to reuse the layout. This code works in the desighn in android studio but when I run it in genymotion it is not as in the desighn:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tel_Iv"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_telephone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loc_Iv"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/web_Iv"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_web" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tel_Et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loc_Et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-270dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/web_Et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-350dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@string/save_info_button"
        android:textColor="@color/buttonText" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi can you please update the pencil drawing of how you want to be displayed

Comment: Hi , there is a link under the code with a picture

Comment: sorry the link is in the beginning of my question

Comment: check my ans and up vote of mark as correct if it solves ur prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say layout_input.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tel_Iv"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_telephone"
    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tel_Et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and layout_form.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/layout_input" />

<include layout="@layout/layout_input" />

<include layout="@layout/layout_input" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-350dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="@string/save_info_button"
    android:textColor="@color/buttonText" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is that all three images and edittexts should be in one layout  to be reused ,, it is three different lines with different images and different edittexts

Comment: 1. If you want to reuse the layout try to set the image in code.
2. Or paste all in in single layout and use image src in xml itself